# why don't I get a black navbar at the top and toggle button shows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

why don't I get a black navbar at the top and toggle button shows?

```
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div><!--navbar-header-->
                </div><!--container-->

            </div><!--navbar-->

        </div><!--navbar-wrapper-->
```

Comment: Please replicate your issue in plunkr, jsfiddle, jsbin etc. So we can help you better. Just by the looks of your code, it looks like it should work.

Comment: here is the full code in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/muveri/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You Bootstrap CSS isn't being loaded. Inspect the page to see if this is showing up / check the path in your file structure. (you also you have jQuery loading twice and no Bootstrap JS in the footer)

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: vanburen, I had a feeling it was something like that and I want to thank you, that's exactly what it was. You spared me hundreds of hours.

Comment: Youre welcome, glad i could help and if the answer worked please mark it as answered so others can benefit from it.